# People going around on a couch

Tags: battlefield-hardline

In Battlefield Hardline, when in "Dust Bowl" map, I often see 2 players going around on a house couch or car backseat (as it seems to me).

What is this and what's the meaning of this thing (apart from fun, the rate of which is very high seeing them :-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The couch is called The American Dream, (called MERICA in the killfeed), it is a hidden vehicle in Battlefield Hardline. It is a couch with four wheels underneath that can be driven by a player and can seat three other passengers. It is found on the map Dust Bowl during the Hotwire gamemode. It spawns in one of three random locations across the map.

The American Dream is the fastest land vehicle in the game, and handles similarly to the Dirt Bike. This allows the couch to perform high-speed jumps and easily roadkill other players. However, the couch offers no protection for its users, who are completely exposed to gunfire, and is very vulnerable to explosives. The couch also spawn once per match, after it is destroyed, it will not reappear for remainder of the round. If the you want to continue using it, then it is important to keep out of large firefights and away from heavier attack vehicles. The driver should make use of its high speed to perform hit-and-run attacks on enemies. Having a passenger equipped with the Repair Tool will also be useful for keeping the couch up and running. Since the couch can be repaired with the Repair Tool.

The "driver" sits on the left-side (from the back) cushion of the couch with his hand on the armrest, the second passenger sits on the right-side cushion with his left leg resting on his right knee, the third sits on the headrest, and the fourth sits on the right armrest. Like other vehicles, the passengers are free to use their personal equipment while the driver remains unarmed.

Source: http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/The_American_Dream